# MySQL COUNT for days

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the value of users visiting my page for 10 days in a chart. I need to COUNT() all the values from the last ten days.

The best layout would be

```
Day|COUNT(ip)

1 - 10
2 - 12
3 - 52
......
```

I hope you understand what I mean. 
Can MySQL do this directly or need I to do this in PHP in 10 seperate querys?

Regards,
Moritz

Update with Tablestructure:

```
    Id (Auto Increment)|Time (Unix Timestamp)|Ip|Referer
```

Comment: You should post your table structure, some sample data and what you have tried.

Comment: Depending on your structure, it looks like you're just looking for a GROUP BY.

Comment: I don't thing group by would work with the unix timestamp for a whole day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Time`)) AS CHAR) as dateoftime, COUNT(Ip) as cnt
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Time`)) > DATE_SUB(current_timestamp, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
GROUP BY CAST(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Time`)) AS CHAR)
```

Comment: Hey, DATE_SUB(Indate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) what is indate? It doesn't exist as a modifier here.

Comment: I edited after I posted,  refresh page and you will see edited answer. Use current_timestamp instead of Indate

Answer (score 2):

This will give you results with actual date values:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip),
    FROM_UNIXTIME(Time, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Day
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    Time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY))
GROUP BY
    FROM_UNIXTIME(Time, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I would suggest the following WHERE clause:  Time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY))

Comment: @bobwienholt: Doesn't matter. Either way does the same thing.

Comment: Not exactly.  Your method will miss the beginning of the first day.

Comment: @bobwienholt: Not at midnight, it wouldn't :-P. Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should run fast for you

```
SELECT COUNT(ip) ipcount,dt FROM
(
    SELECT ip,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`Time`)) as dt FROM mytable
    WHERE `Time` > TO_UNIXTIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
) A GROUP BY dt;
```

Make sure you have an index on `Time`

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX TimeIndex (`Time`);
```